# JSF is not working

Tags: jsf

I am beginner in JSF. I found one example in the Internet but it is not working besides the author said that it was right. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view>
    Label Text:
    <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
</f:view>
</html>
```

After deploying into Tomcat, I can see only "Label Text" in Chrome/Mozila. I am opening code page throught browser and see the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view>
Label Text:
    <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"></h:outputLabel>
</f:view>
</html>
```

What is problem of mine?

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Do you see JSF code when openning source code in web browser?

Comment: yes, I represented it in the end of my first message

Comment: There is something wrong in your `web.xml` configuration, you should not see any JSF code in the source code of the rendered page.

Comment: Paste your web.xml here and also the URL you're using to access the page

Comment: go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/21227775#21227775

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Probably you forget to configure JSF stuffs in web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**2)** another option namespace can be wrong. "xmlns.jcp.org" is jsf 2.2 namescapes. are you sure to have jsf 2.2 dependencies? please try this sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:body>
    Label Text:
    <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: no! my web.xml is pretty good! listen up, when I remove value="Hello, world" from tag and put it lie this:  <h:outputLable>Hello World!</h:outputLabel>, I can normally see "Hello world" in browser. Why can't I use value inside <h:outputLable>?

Comment: when you use value="Hello, world" browser render it like tag attribute and attributes cannot seen. with <h:outputLable>Hello World!</h:outputLabel> you can see "Hello World!". Because browser render it like text node. please see second option in my answer.